# Why was the actor who played Kreese in Community credited as 'Someone Else'?

Tags: credits, community

In Community Season 6 Episode 4 in the stage adaption of Karate Kid, the actor who plays 'Kreese' (real actor in film was [Jess Allen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3748647/) playing Kreese in the original was [Martin Kove](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0184392/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) )

[image]

is given the credit 'Someone else':

[image]

Why didn't they give him his stage character name or a more descriptive character name? Was it just a way of giving funny role names like we'd see in the end credits of the Naked Gun films?